# Lock management and query cost in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking

In the execution of a query we have the estimated subtree cost of a statement and we can also look at e.g. CPU time or logical reads.

Does the estimated subtree cost incorporate the cost of acquiring lock and lock escalation in its formula? Also I guess the process of managing locks requires CPU. Does the CPU time of a query include the CPU time used for lock management and lock related tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimated subtree cost is a rough estimate of query cost, based on the query execution time on [a particular computer 20 years ago](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/).  It's used by the *cost based* query optimizer to evaluate which query plan to choose.

It’s calibrated to account for locking cost, but probably is too rough an estimate to account for lock escalation.

CPU cost of actual query plans is the best single measure of query cost, as most query operations end up consuming CPU time.  In particular CPU time accounts for logical IO, locking, reading data pages, performing calculations and comparisons, etc.

The only part of a query elapsed time that isn't accounted for by CPU time is waits, and waits are normally not *inherent* to a query, but caused by the interaction with other sessions, or by the need to read data not in the page cache, or to commit a transaction to the log file, etc.